# Unable to use asp.net Web Site Administration Tool SQL connection error

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-membership

I am working on IIS 7, SQL Express 2008.

I'm trying to use the Web Site Administration Tool to set up some users in a membership db. I have the tables set up but when I click on the security tab in the web app I get an exception "There is a problem with your selected data store..." the error i get is

```
"The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Cannot open database "ticketinventory" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'sa'"
```

The connection string I am using is `"data source=kyrian-pc\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=ticketinventory;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=******;"`

(I know to not use sa for a connection string, this is just to get it to work initially and I have removed the password with ****** )

I can log into sql with the sa username and password and query the membership tables. If I change the querystring to a fake user name I see the error message in the web app reflect that username so I know it is using the right connection string.

As far as I can tell this should be working but I am obviously missing something. **Any ideas?**

**EDIT**
It turns out the issue has something to do with my connection string itself. I created a test page with this code 
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString))
    {
    conn.Open();
    conn.Close();
    }

and this throws a login exception. For whatever reason my other connection string are being stored in the appSettings so there is some difference that I am now trying to work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite checking it 5 or 6 times I had the db name wrong in the connection string. Problem solved.

"The only infinite things are is the universe itself and the stupidity of man, and I'm not sure about the 1st one" - einstein